# Changing colours in SVG symbol using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, color, svg

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen), and I have imported a traffic cone symbol in SVG format to represent some of my data. I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of this symbol according to the values in one of the columns of my shapefile?

Basically my traffic cone is orange and white, and I would like to change the shade of the orange according to the values in a column of my shapefile. Is it possible to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Anyone know how to do this by any chance?

Comment: Are the values in the column the color values, or some other values? I am not aware that QGIS can do the SVG manipulation. So I would suggest you prepare icons with different shades of orange and do a categorized styling.

Comment: @bennos, yes i think you are right, so that what i started doing...