# SVG symbol colors differences in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: symbology, svg, qgis-2.12

I don't understand why SVG symbols, which are colors changeable in the symbol default installation like this airplane:

[image]

[image]

whereas there symbols like the transport bus station, and lighting symbol (that i have been created in inkscape 0.91) that don't have any option to change the fill colors and the outline?

[image]

[image]

I have red [Changing colours in SVG symbol using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190272/changing-colours-in-svg-symbol-using-qgis) and didn't got suitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the content of the SVG file and an answer was given in  GIS SE ([How to create svg symbols that have modifiable fill color, stroke color and stroke width?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/77421/2581)) and in [Add and personalise SVG symbols in QGIS](http://www.portailsig.org/content/ajouter-et-personnaliser-des-symboles-svg-depuis-qgis) (in French, Portail SIG)

Compare the "transport_bus_stop.svg" file where you can change the colors

[image]

In the file, the `<path` contains many parameters fill, fill_opacity, ...

```
<g><path fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)" d="M290.625,34.563c0.676,0,1.379,0.026,2.063,0.031
c0.688-0.005,1.381-0.031,2.063-0.031H290.625z"/>
```

And the  "transport_bus_station.svg" file where you cannot change the colors, none of them.

[image]

```
<g><path d="M289.075,74.971c0.53,0,1.08,0.021,1.616,0.025c0.539-0.004,1.082-0.025,1.615-0.025H289.075z"/>
```

Therefore if you add these tags (fill=,...) after each "`<path`" and before `d="` in the file:

```
<path fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"d="M289.075,74.971c0.53,0,1.08,0.021,1.616,0.025c0.539-0.004,1.082-0.025,1.615-0.025H289.075z"/>
```

The result is a symbol where you can change the color, the stroke and...

[image]
[image]
[image]

The new paths of the "transport_bus_station.svg" file

```
<g>
<path fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"d="M289.075,74.971c0.53,0,1.08,0.021,1.616,0.025c0.539-0.004,1.082-0.025,1.615-0.025H289.075z"/>
<path fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1" d="M400.596,94.753c-21.278-8.867-72.277-19.462-109.904-19.758c-37.625,0.298-88.604,10.892-109.88,19.758
    c-21.582,8.993-35.975,17.989-40.471,40.47l-16.183,124.644v171.725h27.886v26.933c0,32.837,48.036,32.837,48.036,0v-26.933h88.727
    h0.27h92.228v26.933c0,32.837,48.062,32.837,48.062,0v-26.933h27.886V259.867l-16.183-124.644
    C436.57,112.743,422.178,103.746,400.596,94.753z M222.187,106.456h66.888h70.144c13.489,0,13.489,20.223,0,20.223h-70.291h-66.741
    C208.698,126.679,208.698,106.456,222.187,106.456z M176.085,377.754c-12.729,0-23.063-10.311-23.063-23.039
    s10.333-23.063,23.063-23.063s23.039,10.332,23.039,23.063S188.815,377.754,176.085,377.754z M289.075,272.99H166.806
    c-11.97,0-14.469-8.596-13.294-17.261l12.608-90.392c1.73-10.982,5.435-18.215,19.685-18.215h103.123h106.648
    c14.25,0,17.979,7.233,19.709,18.215l12.608,90.392c1.176,8.665-1.349,17.261-13.318,17.261H289.075z M405.321,377.754
    c-12.729,0-23.063-10.311-23.063-23.039s10.334-23.063,23.063-23.063c12.729,0,23.038,10.332,23.038,23.063
    S418.05,377.754,405.321,377.754z"/>
<path fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1" d="M492.577,87.888C438.591,33.902,366.813,4.17,290.466,4.17S142.34,33.901,88.354,87.888
    C34.368,141.874,4.636,213.652,4.636,290c0,76.348,29.731,148.126,83.717,202.112c53.986,53.985,125.764,83.717,202.112,83.717
    c76.349,0,148.125-29.731,202.111-83.717c53.985-53.986,83.717-125.765,83.717-202.112
    C576.293,213.653,546.563,141.874,492.577,87.888z M290.466,550.692C146.72,550.692,29.774,433.746,29.774,290
    S146.72,29.308,290.466,29.308c143.745,0,260.691,116.946,260.691,260.692S434.211,550.692,290.466,550.692z"/>
</g>
```