# SVG symbol in QGIS 2.18.9

Tags: symbology, style, svg, qgis-2.18

Continuously to:

[SVG symbol colors differences in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199948/svg-symbol-colors-differences-in-qgis-2-12)

i tried to change the color of this pin mark

(i took the svg file from http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/R/Y/M/S/g/map-pin-yellow.svg)

in point layer:

[image]

by opening the notepad of the svg file and adding those line into the notepad of the svg file

```
fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-
width="param(outline-width) 1"
```

but with no result.

Comment: You can open this pin mark with inkscape and change color

Comment: i know it- but i prefer to change the color in the QGIS

Comment: It worked for me? I added this line fill="param(fill)" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity)" stroke="param(outline)" stroke-opacity="param(outline-opacity)" stroke-width="param(outline-width)" into the SVG file with notepad and then changed the colour of the fill in the symbol style  in the layer properties? I am using QGIS 2.18.12 in case that is relevant

Comment: i can't understand what am i doing wrong :-(

Comment: The same line between path and d=  ?

Comment: how can i send you the svg file ? so you can see the lines

Comment: Some svg files can embed png files. When I scroll through the standard SVGs that come installed with QGIS, I see some that are grey/black and others with colour. The grey/black ones I can modify fill and outline. However, I can't modify the coloured ones. Is your SVG purely vector? Or does it contain an image in it?

Comment: Perhaps add the a screenshot of the notepad to your post

Comment: The pin that I am editing from the list of SVGs in the style tab does have drop shadow, where did you find your pin, what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: i will edit my question now

Comment: i found it in http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/R/Y/M/S/g/map-pin-yellow.svg