# Fill transparency of custom SVG symbol

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

I'm trying to create a custom symbol using inkscape and editing the svg file to be able to manage it from the style window in QGIS.

[image]

Edited the .svg symbol file deleting the "style" lines and inserting the line (after "path" and "circle"):

```
fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"
```

I can edit lines colors/thicknesses and the fill color but I do not know how to edit file to get a transparent fill of the symbol. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, after reading [SVG symbol colors differences in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199948/svg-symbol-colors-differences-in-qgis-2-12), I solved the problem by editing the line:

`fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) # 000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"`

Adding `fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity) 0"` i.e.

`fill="param(fill) #FFF" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity) 0" stroke="param(outline) # 000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"`

changing the value of the parameter `param(fill-opacity)` between 0 and 1 it is possible to adjust fill opacity.